# Was doing some update & installs last night (link given below). Upon restart am now given a logon loop & cannot get into my 18.04. How do I repair?

Tags: updates, 18.04, restart

https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu/
Used the above link & once done restarted only to get stuck in a logon loop ie. continuously provide logon details without getting into 18.04.

You all must please bear with me. I'm the original Captain Chaos, whatever I touch tends to break LOL.